# date always showing 01 January 1970

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my model

```
function insert_employee($data) {
    $query = $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

This is my controller

```
function save_header() {
    if (!IS_AJAX) {
        display_nonajax_stop();
        exit;
    } else {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $data = nullify_array($data);

        if ($data['emp_isretire'] == 'N') {
            $data['emp_retiredate'] = NULL;
        }

        $check = $this->m_employee->get_employee_row(array("emp_id" => $data['emp_id']));

        if ($check) {
            $result['message'] = "ID already exist. Please provide other ID";
            $result['status'] = 0;
            echo json_encode($result);
            die();
        }

        $data['emp_opid'] = $this->session->userdata('usr_name');
        $data['emp_update'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data['emp_birthdate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat(strtotime('Y-m-d', $data['emp_birthdate']));
        $data['emp_dtentry'] = DateTime::createFromFormat(strtotime('Y-m-d', $data['emp_dtentry']));
        $data['emp_dtprobation'] = DateTime::createFromFormat(strtotime('Y-m-d', $data['emp_dtprobation']));
        $data['emp_dtpermanent'] = DateTime::createFromFormat(strtotime('Y-m-d', $data['emp_dtpermanent']));
        $data['emp_dtleaving'] = DateTime::createFromFormat(strtotime('Y-m-d', $data['emp_dtleaving']));
        $data['emp_retiredate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat(strtotime('Y-m-d', $data['emp_retiredate']));

        $q = $this->m_employee->insert_employee($data);

        $result = array();
        if ($q > 0) {
            $result['message'] = "Data has been saved";
            $result['status'] = 1;
        } else {
            $result['message'] = "Database operation fail";
            $result['status'] = 0;
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

I don't know where did I go wrong, it starts to return to 1970-01-01 when the inputs are like this:

`1992-05-11`, etc.

But it formats as expected when I input like this:

`1992-05-01`, `1992-05-02`, `1992-05-03`, etc., until `1992-05-09`.

It seems like the error starts when I input a date more than `09` like `10` or more.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: what is your expected out come  for `$data` array.

Comment: Can you post the values of your variables such as `$data['emp_birthdate']`

Comment: @anantkumarsingh any date over 10th, it's always shows 1970-01-01 it comes out normal if i put date below 10th.

Comment: @Uchiha for example, the value is 1992-05-11 and when i execute the submit button it always returns to 1970-01-01

Comment: Just show `$data` array that you have initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you were creating a wrong format within your code

```
 $data['emp_birthdate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data['emp_birthdate']);
                                                      ^^^^^^
```

should be

```
$data['emp_birthdate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data['emp_birthdate']);
                                                     ^^^^^^
```

If your date is `1992-05-11` then your date format is `Y-m-d` not `d/m/Y`

**Edited**

Its because you were converting it into timeStamp using strtotime instead you need to use it as

```
$data['emp_birthdate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat(strtotime('Y-m-d', $data['emp_birthdate']));
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^                               ^^
```

should be

```
$data['emp_birthdate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data['emp_birthdate']);
```

If your `error_reporting` is on then you might be getting an error

> Notice: **A non well formed numeric value encountered in**
>
> Warning: **DateTime::createFromFormat() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in**
>
> Fatal error: **Call to a member function format() on a non-object in**

[Check Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `/` with `-`:

```
<?php

$data['emp_birthdate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['emp_birthdate']);
$data['emp_dtentry'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['emp_dtentry']);
$data['emp_dtprobation'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['emp_dtprobation']);
$data['emp_dtpermanent'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['emp_dtpermanent']);
$data['emp_dtleaving'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['emp_dtleaving']);
$data['emp_retiredate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['emp_retiredate']);
```

As you **edited your question** the **new answer** is:-

```
$data['emp_retiredate'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data['emp_retiredate']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `strtotime()` in all of the date lines, you need to remove that and it will work.

```
var_dump( DateTime::createFromFormat(strtotime('Y-m-d', '1992-05-11')) );
-> bool(false)

var_dump( DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '1992-05-11') );
-> object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "1992-05-11 12:11:35.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

``